# Stern-gerlach experiment for higher spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Can anyone point me to a reference of where they do the stern-gerlach experiment for particles of spin>1/2. I can't seem to find any. I find many discussing the theory, but none actually doing the experiment. I'm looking for experimental results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this quite fits your request for 'particles', but there is a reasonable amount of literature on performing Stern-Gerlach type experiments on molecules and clusters.

I might suggest you start with [Stern-Gerlach deflection spectra of nitrogen oxide radicals](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/90/8/10.1063/1.455808), Gedanken et al., J. Chem Phys. 90 3981 (1989). (A real Gedanken experiment! - I'm sure he never heard that before...).

If that is not quite what you wanted I'll have to think about it some more.

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler to show to students. All of these types of experiments are quite complicated. Strange that it's hard to find. I wonder if there are a shortage of spin 1 atoms for this type of experiment.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but might help

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04632.pdf

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04632 seems to only give the *theory* for performing Stern-Gerlach on an atom with higher angular momentum levels (i.e., doesn't address the question).